# what is the exact problem.Can anyone explain please

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, subprocess

```
import subprocess
interface = 'wlan0'
address = '00:11:22:33:44:66'

subprocess.call('ifconfig' + interface + 'down', shell=True)
subprocess.call('ifconfig' + interface + 'hw ether' + address, shell=True)
subprocess.call('ifconfig' + interface + 'up', shell=True)
```

Output:

[image: for output please check the image please]

Comment: you append without any spacing, it generates one long word. either put spaces in or, better yet, separate your arguments into a list. I would also recommend perhaps doing some tutorials on using linux before diving into hacking

Comment: Welcome.  Please include the error in the question rather than link an image.

Comment: @Nullman why don't you write that up as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
'ifconfig' + interface + 'down'
```

Is not spaced and will produce a single long word `ifconfigwlan0down` instead of the desired `ifconfig wlan0 down`

you have two aproaches to fix this:
Either add spaces `'ifconfig ' + interface + ' down'`

Or the more correct solution is to separate your parameters into a list as that is what the `subprocess` module expects:

```
subprocess.call(['ifconfig', interface, 'down'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['ifconfig', interface, 'hw', 'ether', address], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['ifconfig', interface, 'up'], shell=True)
```